# C++ equivalent for Java Collection.frequency?

Tags: java, c++

I am somehow new to the c++ environment, and I'm trying to transform a code written in java to c++, and i would like to ask if anyone can help me finding an equivalent to java Collection.frequency in c++. the code that I'm trying to transform as the following:

```
List<Integer> foundCount = new ArrayList<~>();
.... // some code goes here  
...
int count3 = Collections.frequency(foundCount,38);
```

i really appreciate the help

Comment: does [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) not work for you?

Comment: actually i didn't use std::count, cuz i didn't know about it. but after trying it its working now.  thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard-API provides `std::count` for counting.

```
vector<int> v = {23 , 34 , 23 , 583 , 34 , 23};
cout << "23 appears " << count(v.begin() , v.end() , 23) << " times in v"
     << endl;
```

Comment: this is what i have tried after reading  your answer:

vector<int> findCount;
int count 3 = std::count(fountCount.begin(), foundCount.end(), 38);
and it seems to work... thank you very much